# PhpStorm. Force index some folders

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Some folders were excluded by PhpStorm automatically. I want to index them, for example, a specific folder with a WordPress theme. Is it possible to add a folder manually to indexed?

*Darkula*

[image]

*Default*

[image]

Comment: Right click folder > Mark directory as > Cancel Exclusion? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html

Comment: What if you add this directory in *File* > *Settings* > *Directories*: define as *Resource root*?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ it was not excluded. In was marked as a source root.

Comment: @A.L no, not helped. It's still gray, only blue changed to pink.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the blue color on the directory icon, it should be indexed since it's marked as *Source*. Did you try to close and reopen PhpStorm?

Comment: @A.L I have even invalidated caches a few times and restarted the IDE. I want to be indexed `stomatology` folder under `theme`. Now it's blue. With resource root it will be pink. And the situation will be similar.

Comment: @D.R. 1) Could you please clarify what exactly is not indexed there? What does not work? 2) Could you please the same screenshot but using light GUI Theme (e.g. Windows (if you are on Windows) or IntelliJ). Same with editor colors -- could you change it to Default color schema. I have some ideas but since I'm not using Darcula I cannot verify it makes any sense 3) Do you have WordPress integration enabled for this project? 4) Have you enabled any VCS integration? 5) Anything interesting in the `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in XXX)

Comment: @LazyOne You are right. The problem was obvious. I have just to edit .gitignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was obvious. All that folders and files were under the `.gitignore`.

Comment: I don't think that it was obvious, that's an interesting answer. I don't see any reason to explain that PhpStorm doesn't index files ignored by git.

Comment: @A.L LazyOne helped me. I knew about it, but before all .gitignores were mine and I haven't paid attention)

Comment: If file is ignored by VCS (`.gitignore` or alike) -- it does not affect indexing in any way (code completion; syntax coloring; etc) -- it must be something else that may prevent indexing (folder marked as excluded etc). In this particular case (*I think*) OP might have been confused by the file colors -- which PhpStorm uses to indicate VCS status and interpreted is as "file not gets indexed".